# Getting an optional title with nameref and xparse

Tags: hyperref, xparse

Suppose I defined an environment with an optional argument (using `xparse`) as in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,xparse}
\newcounter{exercisecounter}
\stepcounter{exercisecounter}
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{o}
{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{Exercise \theexercisecounter:}{Exercise \theexercisecounter (#1):}}
{}
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[My Exercise]
This is my exercise.
\end{exercise}
Above is \nameref{my exercise}, which is Exercise \ref{my exercise}.
\end{document}
```

If I'd like to reference the exercise's title and the exercise counter using `nameref` and `ref`, respectively, how would I go about doing it?  In general, given an arbitrary environment with an optional argument, how would I got about telling `hyperref` to use the optional argument as the title and a specified counter?

I understand that a solution would likely be based on using `xpatch`, but this is the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: You can get into trouble, as `\nameref` is not expandable!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I guess I need to learn a little more about the importance about expandability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the title using [`nameref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nameref)'s `\NR@gettitle` macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,xparse}% hyperref also loads nameref
\newcounter{exercisecounter}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{o}
  {\par\refstepcounter{exercisecounter}%
   Exercise \theexercisecounter
   \IfNoValueF{#1}{ (#1)\NR@gettitle{#1}}%
   :\quad}
  {\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[My Exercise]
This is my exercise.\label{my exercise}
\end{exercise}
Above is \nameref{my exercise}, which is Exercise \ref{my exercise}.
\end{document}
```

Also note, for reference purposes, you need `\refstepcounter` (*inside* the environment). Also, the above setup doesn't do much when you *don't* supply an optional argument. That can be adopted, but then again you won't use `\nameref` when it doesn't have an optional argument...